# Why does Boot Camp in Windows 7 regularly disappear from the tray?

Tags: imac, bootcamp, windows

Boot Camp (Bootcamp.exe) regularly seems to unload itself with Windows 7 64-bit Home Edition. I usually find out when I try to use fn + Volume keys (f11, f12) and it doesn't work. Then I see the Boot Camp losange in the tray area, and when I mouse over it disappears.

As a workaround I have it now pinned to the task bar so I can use the handy Win + number shortcut to reload it quickly, but I'm still puzzled as to why it disappears like that.

Could this have to do with permissions?

Comment: I experience this myself but it doesn't appear to be limited to only the Bootcamp tray icon. Maybe this is a more generic Windows problem?

Comment: Though it happens only with Boot Camp on my Windows 7 configuration, I noticed that it happens when I run games. Could it have to do with memory? The application somehow accepts to be unloaded to free up memory? (I have 4GB)